# Using preventDefault() in Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I,m using PHP, Jquery and Ajax to submit user info, to validate the input fields and submit the info I use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#contact_form").validate({
          ... my validation code goes here ...
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $(form).attr("method"),
                url: $(form).attr("action"),
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                dataType : "json",
                success: function(result){
                                    $("#contact_form").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $("#success_message").fadeIn();
                    });
                                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I know it is very simple but I have a question: do I need to add the preventDefault() method? If the answers is yes, could you please help me with an example?

Thanks.

Comment: `submitHandler` replaces the default form submission for you, so you don't need to call `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you are not required to put e.preventDefault(); since jquery validator does that for you. when the form is submitted the default action of form is prevented by the Jquery validator.